# undefined:1 undefined ^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my code, the data gets logged but then or mid-way the error happends.

The error message is

```
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

```js
function script() {
  request('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty', function(error, res, body){
    for(let i = 0; i <= body.length; i++) {
      let obj = JSON.parse(body)
      request(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${obj[i]}.json?print=pretty`, function(error, res, body){
        let myData = JSON.parse(body);
        if(myData && myData.title && myData.score && myData.id) {
          console.log('TITLE: ', myData.title)
          console.log('UPVOTES: ', myData.score)
          console.log(`https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=${myData.id}`)
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: the value undefined can not be parsed ... so, body is undefined - common error ... you're accessing `body[body.length]`  (arrays start at index 0, as you know, so their length is obviously one greater than the last available index) since you check for `i <= body.length` ... remove the `=` and your code will work without error - I'd also put `let obj = JSON.parse(body)` before the for loop, so you don't unnecessarily repeat the same conversion

Comment: you are parsing the body until its length?

Comment: "the data gets logged" what data? why parse `let obj = JSON.parse(body)` lenght times?

Comment: @JaromandaX I switched back to `< body.length` and moved `let obj = JSON.parse(body)` before the loop and I'm still getting the same error as before.

Comment: @JaromandaX _"you're accessing `body[body.length]`"_ - There's no such (or `body[i]`) piece of code in OPs question...

Comment: Check the `error` of the inner `request(...)` which most likely will have an explanation for your problem.

Comment: @andreas, it's actually worse than I thought, OP is accessing `obj[i]` where obj is JSON.parse(body), so body is a STRING! wow!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably wanted to parse the data and *then* iterate over it:

```js
function script() {
  request('https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty', function(error, res, body){
    let obj = JSON.parse(body)
    for(let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      request(`https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/${obj[i]}.json?print=pretty`, function(error, res, body){
        let myData = JSON.parse(body);
        if(myData && myData.title && myData.score && myData.id) {
          console.log('TITLE: ', myData.title)
          console.log('UPVOTES: ', myData.score)
          console.log(`https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=${myData.id}`)
        }
      })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: It works for me: https://runkit.com/fzs111/stackoverflow.com-a-61866927-8376184